# COUNT function use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement, there is a table CR. Type is a field here. Now it has values like A,B,C. I need separate counts for CR records having type A in month Jan,Feb,...Dec 2013.Same for Type B and C in SQL SERVER 2008. A, B, C will be column headers and count of each for a month-year combination comes under it.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Always show what you done before ask a question.

Comment: Googling first would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need google first before asking this...

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT type, datepart(mm, date) month, count(1) cn
FROM CR
WHERE datepart(yyyy, date) = '2013'
GROUP BY type, datepart(mm, date)
) AS t
PIVOT(MIN(cn) FOR type IN ([A], [B], [C])) AS m
```

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, updated for 2013 only.

Comment: Sorry zhongxiao!! I did it main catch is with the format I just now edited.

Comment: then you need `PIVOT`. See updates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the CR table have a datetime field called dat you can GROUP BY MONTH in this way :

```
SELECT DATEPART(Month, dat) AS month, Type
FROM CR
WHERE  DATEPART(Year, dat) = 2013
GROUP BY Type , DATEPART(Year, dat), DATEPART(Month, dat)
```

Comment: Hi Aleroot! I need one record for each month-year combination, Type values as column header and count of records under that column.Can you please help?

Comment: Ask another, more clear question ... This is not a forum, it's a Q&A,